# Extracting Imported Information

Tags: plotting, matrix, import, probability-or-statistics, visualization

What I want to do is to compare the relationship between the consumption of say beer and wine using scatter plots where each point designates the particular country (preferably named). I have tried to part the information - so that each particular column becomes a vector - using the function Part without any success. I find this bewildering given that `Dimension[data]` yields the result `{19,4}`.

For those of you that are familiar with R: What I would like to do to is to part the information, like this

```
    > Country <-data$Country
    > Beer <-data$Beer
    > Wine <-data$Wine
    > HardLiquid <-data$HardLiquid
```

and then produce scatter plots which names every country.

```
> plot(Beer,Wine,type="n")
> text(Beer,Wine,Country)
```

**Extra**

This is the data that I am working on in *Mathematica*:

```
data = {{"Country", "Beer", "Wine", "Hard Liquid"}, 
 {"Sweden", 56., 16., 2.9}, 
 {"Danmark", 98., 32., 2.7}, 
 {"Finland", 79., 10., 5.7}, 
 {"Norway", 56., 11., 2.4}, 
 {"Belgium", 98., 30., 2.6},
 {"France", 47., 41., 7.2}, 
 {"Irland", 155., 13., 5.3}, 
 {"Italy", 29., 54., 2.7}, 
 {"Netherlands", 80., 20., 4.7}, 
 {"Switzerland", 57., 42., 2.4}, 
 {"Kingdom United", 20., 97., 3.9}, 
 {"Germany", 26., 119., 5.3}, 
 {"Austria", 36., 106., 3.2}, 
 {"USA", 85., 7., 4.8}, 
 {"Canada", 70., 10., 4.3}, 
 {"Australia", 21., 89., 2.6}, 
 {"Nya Zeeland", 19., 78., 2.3}, 
 {"Japan", 55., 10., 8.2}}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know, I simply copied the cell.

Comment: `ListPlot[Tooltip[{#2, #3}, #] & @@@ data[[ 2 ;;]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Beer", "Wine"}]`?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `Part` right? You say "I tried to part the information using `Part`", which sounds curious to me. Note that the main use of `Part` is not to part something into multiple parts, but rather to get a part of the expression. In your case `data[[2;; ,2]]]` should give you a list of the values in the beer consumption column. But see also Kuba's code, which shows that you can skip getting the columns altogether.

Comment: I encounter the following message when when I use Kuba's code: "ListPlot::lpn : TableForm[] is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers". As for the second question; I apparently don't seem to use it correctly. After all, I don't obtain the desired outcome. Nevertheless, I have tried the same argument in other instance and been successful, which is to say I have managed to isolate the columns without any error messages. As I have stated above; I find this bewildering.

Comment: If your code for `data` is missing `,`s then it will fail. How did you import the data?

Comment: @user12779 it appears you are dealing with a hidden wrapper `TableForm` around your data. You can use `FullForm` to see if it is present, or perhaps you can see what `Head[data]` is. If it is `TableForm`, try to find out where you add `TableForm` and undo this.

Comment: I imported the data using Import["Desktop/beerwinehardliquid.xls"]. As for the second part, I have undone the TableForm, yet the same problem persists.

Comment: However, if I write ListPlot[Tooltip[{#2, #3}, #] & @@@ data[[1, All]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"Beer", "Wine"}], then everything is fine except I don't get any of the names of the countries.

Comment: @user12779 It is a mouseover thing, move your mouse over the data points and you will see the names :)

Comment: That is great! Nevertheless, what I really would like to have is some sort of PlotLegends on the right that would identify each country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = DynamicModule[{col = Black}, 
   DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@Style[#, col], 
                  If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], col = Red; pos = {#2, #3}, 
                                                col = Black; pos = {}]]] &;

With[{d1 = Rest@data}, 
     ListPlot[{{#2, #3}} & @@@ d1, BaseStyle -> {PointSize@.02, 15, Bold}, 
                                   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
              Epilog -> {Inset[Grid@Partition[f @@@ d1, 2], Scaled@{.7, .6}], 
                         Thick, PointSize@.05, Opacity@.5, Dynamic@Point[pos]},
              PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, Scaled@.5}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for introducing me to `DynamicWrapper` and its joys +1 seems to small...:)

Comment: @ubpdqn I'm glad you like it :) I'm not sure if `DynamicWrapper` is the best choice here but the more diversity in answers the more we all are learning :)

Comment: Same here @Kuba, first time to see this function.

Comment: That is absolutely wonderful! Thanks Kuba!